# Android App, Write file to shared network folder on windows 7

Tags: android, windows, directory, shared

My Computer and my xperia are in the same network.
I got a Windows 7 system.
One folder is shared. Everyone inside of the network can write and read everything from that folder.

Right now I want the app, that I develop, to write a simple .txt-file to that shared folder.
Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance,
Shera

Comment: Possible?  Probably.  Simple - no - you'd have to provide an implemention a windows compatible file sharing protocol within the package of your app itself, as Android does not have system-level support for that.  You might see if anyone has ported samba.

Comment: the most simple way you can do is making a service on computer side. you'll send data to server and it will write into txt.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway.
I already thought so myself. Of course a webservice would be more easy. I just wanted to know if there is an easy way to do it without a webservice.